# "In my career as" — is "as" correct here?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, collocation

I have this fragment:

> ... the experience and knowledge gained will be helpful in my career as a neuropathologist.

Is the "as" here okay? It somehow does not sound right to me. Obviously I want to say that it will be helpful to me, during my career in neuropathology.

Comment: It's fine. The fragment is ambiguous as to whether you've already started your career as a neuropathologist (that could be your future goal *after* you've gained this particular experience and knowledge), but that's not really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

In English, writers and speakers commonly use *as* to introduce a narrower category or framework within which a subject already introduced is to be considered. *As* appears in a role similar to the one it plays in "my career as a neuropathologist" in such book titles as *Illness as Metaphor*, *The World as Will and Representation* (admittedly an English translation of a German title), *A Portrait of the Artist as a Young Man*, *My Life as a Dog*, and *A Portrait of the Artist as a Young Dog*.

Here's the relevant definition in Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary, eleventh edition (2003):

> **as** *prep[osition]* **2 :** in the capacity, character, condition, or role of {works *as* an editor}

On a separate note, I recommend that you address the problem of ambiguity that FumbleFingers points out in a comment beneath your question. One way to indicate whether your career in neuropathology has already begun is to change "my career as a neuropathologist" to something like "the career in neuropathology that I've already embarked on." If you haven't yet begun your career as a neuropathologist, you can make this clear by adding the word *future* before *career.*